# R Packages won't install via ansible (ALMA Linux 8)

Tags: ansible, r

## Problem

I would like to use ansible to provision a virtual box. This box will need to do multiple things, but it needs to have R installed as well as some specific packages that aren't included in base R.

I use the vagrant file provided below to create a new virtual machine and then install ansible, epel-release and git using yum. On this virtual machine I then use the "Alma Linux 8" and "Docker" playbooks provided below before the one I believe to be problematic.

I then run this playbook to install R

```
---
- name: "Setup R on the local machine"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  tasks:

  # Update all installed packages

  - name: Update all packages to their latest version
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: "*"
      state: latest

  # Install EPEL to get extra packages

  - name: Install EPEL
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: epel-release
      state: latest

  # Enable the Code Ready Builder (CRB) repository

  - name: Install utilities to enable package repositories
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: yum-utils
      state: latest

  - name: Enable the PowerTools repository
    become: yes
    shell: dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools

  # Install R

  - name: Install R
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: R
      state: latest
```

After running this playbook I can then run the command

```
Rscript --slave --no-save --no-restore-history -e "print('Test')"
[1] "Test"
```

showing that R is working at least in some capacity. But then when I try and use this to install a package I get this error

```
Rscript --slave --no-save --no-restore-history -e "install.packages('tidyverse')"
```

> Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages("tidyverse") :
> 'lib = "/usr/lib64/R/library"' is not writable
> Error in install.packages("tidyverse") : unable to install packages
> Execution halted

## Attempted Fix

I have attempted to fix this by appending these lines on to the end of the R playbook above

```
- name: Make directory writable
  become: yes
  file:
    path: /usr/lib64/R/library
    mode: '0777'

- name: Make directory writable
  become: yes
  file:
    path: /usr/share/doc/R/html
    mode: '0777'
```

to manually make the problematic directories readable, but this has not worked.

## Reference Files

### Vagrant File

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "almalinux/8"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "2048"
        vb.cpus = 2
    end
    
end
```

### Ansible Playbooks

#### Alma Linux 8

```
---
- name: "Setup AlmaLinux 8 on the local machine"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:

  # Install the base operating systemctl

  - name: Update all packages to their latest versions
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: '*'
      state: latest

  - name: Install virtual machine support
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: open-vm-tools
      state: latest

  # Install EPEL to get extra packages

  - name: Install EPEL
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: epel-release
      state: latest
```

#### Docker

```
---
- name: "Setup Docker on the local machine"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  tasks:

  # Install Docker

  - name: Uninstall any older versions of Docker
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name:
        - docker
        - docker-client
        - docker-client-latest
        - docker-common
        - docker-latest
        - docker-latest-logrotate
        - docker-logrotate
        - docker-engine
      state: absent

  - name: Install yum-utils to install a new package repository
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name: yum-utils
      state: latest

  - name: Install the Docker Repository
    become: yes
    shell: yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

  - name: Install Docker
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.package:
      name:
        - docker-ce
        - docker-ce-cli
        - containerd.io
        - docker-buildx-plugin
        - docker-compose-plugin
      state: latest

  - name: Enable the docker service
    become: yes
    shell: systemctl enable docker

  - name: Enable the containerd service
    become: yes
    shell: systemctl enable containerd

  - name: Start the docker service
    become: yes
    shell: systemctl start docker

  - name: Start the containerd service
    become: yes
    shell: systemctl start containerd

  - name: Ensure docker group exists
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.group:
      name: docker
      state: present

  - name: Add the vagrant user to the docker group
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.user:
      name: vagrant
      groups: docker
      append: yes
```

Comment: Your **Attempted Fix** is a bad idea; and what happens when you run `sudo Rscript --slave --no-save --no-restore-history -e "install.packages('tidyverse')"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But then when I try and use this to install a package

you're doing this as normal user, but are trying to install into system directories, that's the problem here.

Do you want to install system-wide? Then do it as root. Do you just need the packages for that one user? Then don't install system-wide.